# What gives the systems available shares?

Tags: networking, samba

if in gui system admin i bring up the samba shares it gives one answer. if i bring up the gui list of systems shares it brings up another. If i go to a windows machine and maybe some how get it to tell me what shares the samba machine has it gives up a different list. What is a valid way to find the definitive shares  on the ubuntu machine it is offering to the world?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `smbclient` command

```
$ smbclient -L server
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter user's password: # press Enter here for anonymous/guest login
Anonymous login successful

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
public_share    Disk      Ubuntu Public Share
...
```